# Syntax error in Cucumber+Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I have the following part of a step definition:

```
page.should have_content "Contraseña o Email incorrecto."
```

And I get a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
  page.should have_content "Contraseña o Email incorrecto."
```

If I change the ñ for a n it works smoothly.  Any experiences on codification problems with Capybara/Cucumber/Rspec?

Comment: Are you sure this is a Capybara/Cucumber/Rspec error, rather than Ruby having trouble parsing multibyte chars? What happens if you run `ruby -e "test = \"ñ\""`?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure the cause of the problem, but when running that command nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is is indeed because you've got a utf-8 character in there. Put this line at the top of the spec and Ruby will be happy:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```